# How can I do a for comprehension with if/elif, and no else?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to create a comprehension for from this:

```
for w in s:
    if w in pw_set:
        a[w] += 1
    elif t in nw_set:
        a[w] += 1
```

I have something like this but it doesn't work

```
[(a[w]+=1) if (w in pw_set) else (a[w]+=1) if (w in nw_set) for w in s]
```

Comment: What you have written is not a suitable use of a list comprehension. You are better off with your for-loop.

Comment: Alrigth then, thank you :)

Comment: What is "t"? What is "a"?

Comment: w is the word from s, a list, and a is a dictionary (key:w, value: occurrency)

Answer (score 1):

If you really, **absolutely** want to do that with a list comprehension, you'll need a `collections.Counter` to accumulate the results into. (It can count occurrences from a flat list of values.)

```
> pw_set = {'a','b', 'c'}
> nw_set = {}
> s = ['a', 'b', 'q', 'z', 'e']
> a = collections.Counter(
    [
        w
        for w in (
            w if (w in pw_set or w in nw_set) else None
            for w in s
        )
        if w is not None
    ]
)
Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1})
```

Comment: Is it faster than the for loop I wrote in the question? The idea I had was that each element of both sets are a combined dictionary key set which each value is the occurrency from the word.

Comment: No, this will likely be slower.

Comment: Okay then, thank you so much :)